# Is there an "only if" statement in R?

Tags: r

It is my understanding that the `if` and `else` statements parallel conditional logic. Is there an R expression (alternatively, a function) that mirrors *only if* statements?

For instance, the following script will print `Yoda` since the condition is satisfied:

```
x <- "force"
if(x == "force"){ print("Yoda") }

[1] "Yoda"
```

Whereas, this will not:

```
if(x != "force"){ print("Yoda") }
```

So if R prints `Yoda`, then we know that `x` is `force`. However, R could have printed `Yoda` for other reasons too. Perhaps I might have forgotten about a statement in my environment called:

```
if(y == "Jedi_Learning"){ print("Yoda") }
```

Then we would expect R to print `Yoda` whenever the `y`'s `Jedi_Learning` is called in the script. In which case, `Yoda` could appear when either `Jedi_Learning` or `force` calls onto the R stage.

That said, my question is, is there a logical expression that works like this? (totally hypothetical here):

```
onlyif(z == "Star_Wars" ){ print("Yoda") }
```

The above expression would suppress every other statement that summons `Yoda`. `Yoda` would appear only if there is a `Star_Wars` in `z`.

Comment: Does any programming language support an assertion that this `then` clause can never be used ever again? (That's what I'm interpreting from your question.) (BTW: off the cuff, I'm thinking "No".)

Comment: Well, I remember using ``http://logiclx.humnet.ucla.edu`` in college to study for philosophy. As I can recall it, some logical expressions containing ``only if`` expressions could have been nullified with another only if. So, I would say that this ``then`` clause could be used again.

Comment: I edited my question's wording and replaced ``nullify`` with ``prevent``. The former implies that ``Jedi_Learning`` and ``force`` cancels, but they do not. They just do not summon ``Yoda`` without ``Star_Wars``.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to have a function which runs the first time it is called and on subsequent invocations just returns NULL?

Comment: A self-destructing function? Nice thought, @G.Grothendieck ... not sure how I'd use it, but interesting thought. (I'm guessing it's not actually self-destructing, it just has self-destructing "cargo", is that what you were thinking?)

Comment: "only if" (P <- Q) is a backwards "if" (P -> Q), so you'd have to write code to check whether "Yoda" is printed to decide whether `z` is "Star_Wars". Which is admittedly not very useful. Running the risk that any line you right may be nullified would be a hard way to program, too, though. To get deeper, I think you're looking at control flow as if it is logical propositions, which it is not. It *uses* logic to determine what to run. Similarly, `x = x + 1` means different things in algebra and programming. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if

Comment: I think this would violate the general notion that an R script can be run consecutively, one line at a time.

Comment: Implementation of a print only once function could either be via a global flag and an if statement in the body of the function or another approach could be to actuallly zap its body.  For example, `printOnce <- function(x) {
  body(printOnce) <<- {};
  print(x)
};
printOnce("x");
printOnce("x")`

Comment: There are notions of state in programming that are relevant to this conversation, too. Some state changes cannot be redone, like deleting a file.

Comment: I have so much to learn, reading your comments.

Comment: You might enjoy prolog or another 'declarative' style language? (as opposed to imperative) But you definitely can't appeal to a statement that involves knowing what happens in every other possible execution path, because you'd run into the halting problem and be profoundly toasted.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, how about `printOnce <- local({ .set <- list(); function(x) { if (!x %in% .set) { .set <<- c(.set, x); print(x) } else stop(); } })`? I like your use of over-writing `body()`, and this alternative allows an arbitrary number of write-once messages. (I can see *some* utility: specific coded error messages that can be traced to exactly one line of code; the unfortunate thing is you don't know that you have a duplicate until it fires twice in one session. Oops, maybe not there. :-)